# Integrating Authorize.net in VueJS3 using Accept.js

Tags: vuejs3, payment-gateway, authorize.net, payment-processing, accept.js

I want to integrate Authorize.net in Vuejs3 front end using Accept.js library but the libray is giving error, is the library updated one or we have a new version?

I have gone through the documentation and tried the same but it was not working

Need a solution to integrate Authorize.net payment services using Vuejs Front end

Below is the error it is giving every time

AcceptUI.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')

```
at p (AcceptUI.js:1:1342)

at t (AcceptUI.js:1:234)

at document.readyState.document.onreadystatechange (AcceptUI.js:1:5791)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we are not all that familiar with the way that Auth.Net works.
This may not be helpful, but we work with a company called USIO for our payment processing and they have an API intended to be called from front end code.
The product is called checkout and provides a prebuilt UI as well as a way to embed the fields in your page.
When you get ready to submit the payment you do a client-side call to create a temporary token.
You would then pass the temporary token back to your server side to process the actual payment or convert it to a permanent token.
There is no special JS that you have to import, its just a simple HTTP post.
If you are interested, I would be happy to share more information on how we did our implementation.